# Android service receives/intercept "home long pressed" event (similar to "Home Button Launcher")

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service, android-broadcast

I am developing an app which needs to receive/intercept event of long pressed home button. I believe this function can be implemented by broadcast receiver intent filter because an existing app called "Home Button Launcher (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamicg.homebuttonlauncher&hl=en)" but I can't find any relevant discussion about how to do it.

When this app is installed and the home button is pressed for a long time (3~5 secs), Android ask users to choose which application need to be launched (either the default Google search or the installed Home button launcher), as shown in https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dynamicg.homebuttonlauncher&hl=en

There are many posts discuss about how to get home button event in applications for knowing when their apps are closed by users but there is no post about how to get this broadcasted event in service.

Does anyone know how I can receive/intercept this event as what Home button launcher does?

Comment: hmmm, but there is a source code of this app, are you too lazy to take a look on it?

Comment: Thank you for mentioning it!!! I haven't noticed there is a source code of this app. I will check it an share the way they did to others! Thanks!

Comment: i think it is an ASSIST intent

Comment: Yes, you are right!! It is! Thanks for much

Comment: So can I intercept and override default home long-press home button behaviour and stop recent-apps dialog or google search from showing up?

Answer (score 0):

Thank for the remind posted by Selvin. The only thing is to add this intent filter in manifest file:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ASSIST" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
```